# How split java string using character which does not have an escape character before it

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I've a string like this:

```
a=b\=c
```

and I need to split it using java `split` method such that my assertion does not throw an exception:

```
String[] res = "a=b\\=c".split("SPLIT_REGEX");
assert (res[0].equals("a") && res[1].equals("b\\=c"));
```

I've tried `[^\\]=` as `SPLIT_REGEX` but it does not give me the desired answer. Could anybody tell me what would be the correct regex for my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind before `=` to skip splitting in `\=`:

```
String res = "a=b\\=c";
String[] toks = res.split("(?<!\\\\)=");
//=> ["a", "b\\=c"]
```

`(?<!\\\\)` is negative lookahead that asserts failure when `\` is present before `=`

Comment: You can't handle right escaped characters this way.

Comment: @revo Could you explain more?

Comment: Actually it depends on your input strings whether or not it is possible for them to produce such cases. For example what should be the expected output if you have this string `"a=b\\\\=c"`? @EhsanKhodarahmi